# Need to see actual rows affected after an Insert, update, delete SQL Trigger

Tags: sql, triggers, sp-send-dbmail

I am trying to capture only those records which were actually updated. The application is first deleting all the records and then re-inserting them so it hard for me to send an email alert for which record was affected.

For example if a table has 5 records and lets say I want to remove record# 3 using application (3rd party) which is removing all 5 records and then re-insert 4 records and the trigger would send 5 removal and 4 addition alerts. Ideally it should send only 1 alert for the record that was removed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This depends on the database you are using.  Some databases don't even update records if there are no changes.

Comment: Its the application, it deletes all the records first and then re-inserts the records from the form.